# Prolog, count how many different values there are in a list

Tags: prolog

I'm new in prolog, and I wanted to create a "function" to count how many different values I have in a list.
I've made this predicate to count the total number of values:

```
tamanho([],0).
tamanho([H|T],X) :- tamanho(T,X1), X is X1+1.
```

I wanted to follow the same line of thought like in this last predicate.(Don't know if that's possible).
So in a case where my list is [1,2,2,3], the answer would be 3.
Can someone give me a little help?

Comment: Just `sort` the list (which removes duplicates), then take its `length`. `sort` is optimized in swi-prolog - https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=sort/2

Answer (score 2):

Here is a pure version which generalizes the relation. You can not only count but just see how elements have to look like in order to obtain a desired count.
In SWI, you need to [install](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pack/list) `reif` first.

```
:- use_module(library(reif),[memberd_t/3]).
:- use_module(library(clpz)). % use clpfd in SWI instead
:- op(150, fx, #).            % backwards compatibility for old SWI

nt_int(false, 1).
nt_int(true, 0).

list_uniqnr([],0).
list_uniqnr([E|Es],N0) :-
   #N0 #>= 0,
   memberd_t(E, Es, T),
   nt_int(T, I),    
   #N0 #= #N1 + #I,
   list_uniqnr(Es,N1).
                                 
tamanho(Xs, N) :-
   list_uniqnr(Xs, N).

?- tamanho([1,2,3,1], Nr).
   Nr = 3.
?- tamanho([1,2,X,1], 3).
   dif:dif(X,1), dif:dif(X,2).
?- tamanho([1,2,X,Y], 3).
   X = 1, dif:dif(Y,1), dif:dif(Y,2)
;  Y = 1, dif:dif(X,1), dif:dif(X,2)
;  X = 2, dif:dif(Y,1), dif:dif(Y,2)
;  Y = 2, dif:dif(X,1), dif:dif(X,2)
;  X = Y, dif:dif(X,1), dif:dif(X,2)
;  false.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fix your code by adding 1 to the result that came from the recursive call if `H` exists in `T`, otherwise, the result for `[H|T]` call is the same result for `T` call.

```pl
tamanho([],0).
tamanho([H|T], X) :- tamanho(T, X1), (member(H, T) -> X is X1; X is X1 + 1).
```

Tests

```
/*
?- tamanho([], Count).
    Count = 0.

?- tamanho([1,a,21,1], Count).
    Count = 3.

?- tamanho([1,2,3,1], Count).
    Count = 3.

?- tamanho([1,b,2,b], Count).
    Count = 3.
*/
```

<s>In case the input list is always numerical</s>, you can follow @berbs's suggestion..

`sort/2` succeeds if input list has non-numerical items<sup>[1]</sup> so you can use it without any restrictions on the input list, so `tamanho/2` could be just like this

```
tamanho(T, X) :- sort(T, TSorted), length(TSorted, X).
```

---

<sup>[1]</sup> thanks to @Will Ness for pointing me to this.

Comment: try `sort([1,a,21,1],X)`.

Comment: What?? It worked! Interesting

Comment: see https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=sort/2. it says "... list ... sorted to the [standard order of terms](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=standardorder)".

Comment: Learned something new today, thank you, I've updated the answer